# AWS Application Load Balancer with lambda as target not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a AWS Application Load Balancer configured as such:

1. interface-facing, ipv4
2. listens on HTTP protocol, port 80, default to target group "lambda-default";
3. target group "lambda-default" targets on lambda function also named as "lambda-default";
4. security group has "all traffic" as inbound and outbound rules.

The lambda function "lambda-default" has nothing but some test code:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    console.log('=========default being called=========')
    console.log(JSON.stringify(event))
    const response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "statusDescription": "200 OK",
        "isBase64Encoded": false,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "text/html"
        },
        "body": "<h1>Hello from Lambda!</h1>"
    }
    return response;
};
```

I hit the DNS name of my alb in the browser, as well as in CLI using curl, none worked. It doesn't return anything. curl request returns something like: `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`.

I checked "monitor" tab for alb, nothing there, seems like alb didn't get any requests at all. Here's a screenshot: [alb monitor tab screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xvbq4.png)

I checked logs for lambda as well. All the requests in the logs are triggered by "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0". There's no requests triggered by alb.

I checked security group. It allows all traffic. It shouldn't be the cause. Here's a screenshot:
[security group screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gb3kr.png)

I also checked some tutorial videos, e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=56a-wAeEl7E They're doing the same thing. The only difference is they have additional listener on HTTPS port 443. But i don't think that's the reason.

So am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you publish your function and used current version/alias in your target group?

Comment: Are you sure you are hitting http and not https?

Comment: @Marcin yes i published it and set the target group the target the $LATEST version of the function

Comment: @Riz i think so, i hit `http://lambda-alb-1845470402.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com`, nothing returns

Comment: Hi @icedcoke, I hope you try to understand what the actual cause is/was as it doesn't make any sense that opening only port 80 solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the cause. I created another security group and only allow http protocol as inbound rule and it works.